# Recycler view filter is not giving desired result in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view with a filter. When I load the data into the recycler view the first time, it gives me a perfect result, but when I use the search option, it is not giving me the result I wanted.

I want to show an activate button when the user field status is deactivated in the database, and show a deactivate button when the user field status is activated in the database. However, after performing the search it's not happening.

This image is giving me perfect result when I load first-time recycler view:
[image: This image is giving me perfect result when I load first-time recycler view]

This image after search result but not giving the result I wanted:
[image: This image after search result but not giving the result I wanted]

Below is my adapter class

```
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<UserHelperClass> mFilteredList;
    private final List<UserHelperClass> mDataList;

    public User_Control_adapter_class(Context mContext,List<UserHelperClass> mFilteredList) {
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.mFilteredList = mFilteredList;
        mDataList = new ArrayList<>(mFilteredList);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filteredList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_control_single_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final UserHelperClass userHelperClass = mFilteredList.get(position);

        holder.fullname.setText(userHelperClass.getFullname());
        holder.aadhar.setText(userHelperClass.getUsername());
        holder.stationid.setText(userHelperClass.getStationid());
        holder.contactno.setText(userHelperClass.getContactno());


        if (userHelperClass.getStatus().equals("Active")) {
            holder.activate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.deactivate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    holder.copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(userHelperClass.getUsername(), userHelperClass.getUsername());
            Toast.makeText(mContext, userHelperClass.getUsername()+ " Copied Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
    });

    holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + userHelperClass.getContactno()));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);



        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    private final Filter filteredList = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<UserHelperClass> filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filterlist.addAll(mDataList);
            } else {
                String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (UserHelperClass item : mDataList) {
                    if (item.getFullname().toLowerCase().contains(pattern)) {
                        filterlist.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filterlist;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredList.clear();
            mFilteredList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };


    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView fullname, aadhar, contactno, stationid;
        Button activate, deactivate, viewEOD, viewCertificate, copy;
        ImageButton call;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_single_name);
            aadhar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_single_aadhar);
            contactno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_single_contact);
            stationid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_single_stationid);

            activate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_active_button);
            deactivate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_deactive_button);
            viewEOD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_View_EOD_button);
            viewCertificate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_control_certificate_button);
            copy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copy_button);

            call = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);

        }
    }
}
```

Below is my User_control class

```
    public class User_Control extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private List<UserHelperClass> mDataList=new ArrayList<>();
    private User_Control_adapter_class mRecyler_View_User_Control_Adapter;
    TextInputLayout searchText;
    String search_string;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user__control);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.custome_toolbar);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        searchText=findViewById(R.id.textlayout_search_layout_user_control);
        search_string= Objects.requireNonNull(searchText.getEditText()).toString().trim();


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
        Sprite fadingCircle = new Circle();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(fadingCircle);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        getUserInformation();

        searchText.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                mRecyler_View_User_Control_Adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }
        });

    }
    //end of OnCreate



    private void getUserInformation() {
        DatabaseReference mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        mRef.orderByChild("username").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if (snapshot1.exists())
                    {
                        UserHelperClass userHelperClass=snapshot1.getValue(UserHelperClass.class);
                        assert userHelperClass !=null;
                        if(!userHelperClass.getUsername().equals("1"))
                        {
                            mDataList.add(userHelperClass);
                        }

                    }else
                    {
                        Log.d("Error","No Snapshot exists");}
                }
                RecyclerView mRecylerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_user_control);
                mRecylerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(User_Control.this);
                mRecyler_View_User_Control_Adapter=new User_Control_adapter_class(User_Control.this,mDataList);
                mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                mRecylerView.setAdapter(mRecyler_View_User_Control_Adapter);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d("Database Error","Failed to fatch data from the server");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, I think it's working..!

```
    private final Filter filteredList = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<UserHelperClass> filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filterlist.addAll(mDataList);
        } else {
            String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (UserHelperClass item : mDataList) {
                if (item.getFullname().toLowerCase().contains(pattern) && item.getStatus().equals("Active")) {
                    filterlist.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filterlist;
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mFilteredList.clear();
        mFilteredList.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint bro...I made it after the hint. Just changed little in the code.

Comment: Welcome brother

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark Rotteveel. I'll try my best next time